# Why is my circular ImageButton not working?

Tags: android, android-image, android-imagebutton

I'm trying to create a round circular image button in Android. I don't want to use `CircleImageView` because its scale type is `centerCrop` and you can't change that. I want my scale type to be `fitCenter` or `centerInside`.

This is my code for my `ImageButton`:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/profile_image_view"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_image_button"
    android:src="@drawable/default_profile"/>
```

This is my `circle_image_button.xml` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:color="@android:color/white" android:width="2dp" />
            <size android:width="96dp" android:height="96dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

When I run my app, the image is placed on top of the circle. So basically it does not scale down and fit inside of the circle. All you see is a square image. I want the image to fit inside the circle and be able to see the white stroke. How do I fix this?

Comment: can you add some screenshots to help us solve?

Comment: Setting the background (with the `android:background` tag is not ich different than setting the image (`android:src`). You basically end up having to images sitting on top of each other, that's all. To get the desired result,  you might want to look into [PorterDuff.Mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode). You will most likely have to build a custom view (especially if you want to use it in multiple places) that takes your image and applies the correct overlay mode to it (or find a library that fits your needs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only scaletype is your issue I will suggest you to use [ShapeableImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/imageview/ShapeableImageView?hl=en), this will let you add shaped to you imageview and you can add the scaletype at your own usecase, for e.g.:

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:shapeAppearance="@style/RoundedImageViewShape"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
```

and style RoundedImageViewShape, can be:

```
<style name="RoundedImageViewShape">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CardView` with no `cardElevation` and `app:cardCornerRadius` that is exactly half the `CardView` width/height

Here I use one `ImageView` for the frame, and another for the photo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:cardCornerRadius="100dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/default_profile" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/circle_image_button" />


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result

[image]